# Way to test the order of elements in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Just want to implement the unit test for my react component with using the  `Jest` and `Enzyme`.

Is there a way to test the order? Let's say I have component **Button**, and I want to render icon and text at the same time.

And of course it's good to provide the alignment option to the user(Icon first or Children first).

**Button.js**

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        let content;
        const icon = (<Icon type='search' />);
        if (this.props.iconAlign === 'right') {
            content = (<span>{this.props.children} {icon}</span>
        } else {
            content = (<span>{icon} {this.props.children}</span>
        }
        return (
            <button>{content}</button>
        );
    }
}
```

How to test the `iconAlign` props with **Jest** and **Enzyme**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a shallow render and compare the output. I am not familiar with the Jest syntax so that side of my example may be incorrect (I quickly referred to their website):

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe(`Button`, () => {
  it(`should render the icon on the right`, () => {
    const children = <div>foo</div>;
    const actual = shallow(
      <Button iconAlign="right" children={children} />
    );
    const expected = (
      <button><span>{children} <Icon type='search' /></span></button>
    );
    expect(actual.matchesElement(expected)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And then you could create another test for the "left" align.

---

The enzyme version of @pshoukry's answer.

```
describe(`Button`, () => {
  it(`should render icon on the right`, () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Button iconAlign="right">
        <div>foo</div>
      </Button>
    );
    const iconIsOnRight = wrapper.find('span').childAt(1).is(Icon);
    expect(iconIsOnRight).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

---

For reference, here is the enzyme shallow rendering API documentation: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md

Answer (score 5):

Check on the type of the component

**Check icon first**

```
var button = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Button />);

var buttonNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(button);
expect(buttonNode.props.children[0].type.name).toEqual("Icon")
```